# Looking for function to solve the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the question:

For which $A,\varphi$ does the function $A\sin(x+\varphi)$ solve the differential equation $(y')^2+y^2=1$?

I'm new to differential equations and I have no idea what this is supposed to mean.  How do I use the function $A\sin(x+\varphi)$ to solve the differential equation?  I can not find any example in my textbook that looks anything like the problem I have to solve here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We replace $y$ by $A\sin(x+\varphi)$ in the differential equation and find the appropriate values of $A$ and $\varphi$.

Since $y=A\sin(x+\varphi)$ then $y'=A\cos(x+\varphi)$ and then 
$$(y')^2+y^2=1\iff A^2\cos^2(x+\varphi)+A^2\sin^2(x+\varphi)=A^2=1\iff A=\pm1$$
hence 
$$y=\pm\sin(x+\varphi),\ \forall \varphi\in\mathbb R$$
is a solution for the differential equation.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize it was that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start

$$ y(x)= A\sin(x+\phi) \implies  y'(x)= A\cos(x+\phi)$$

Substitute back in the ode and you will find the answer.

**Note:**

> $$ \sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)=1 $$